# Are Julia ML libraries inherently parallelized and optimized?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, julia

I am trying to decide if I should learn Julia or stick with Python and its libraries, e.g. TensorFlow and FastAI. One important consideration is whether Julia has a library with similar capabilities but without the need for wrappers similar to TensorFlow's AutoGraph. If I write Julia code, is it mostly optimized and parallelized to the level of TensorFlow AutoGraph-generated code?